# sendrawtransaction creates hash but does not propogate to the network

Tags: raw-transaction

I'm on testnet, I've created a raw tx and I'm using bitcoind. I've confirmed that the hex is formed correctly and signrawtransaction returns complete:true.

After I've run bitcoind sendrawtransaction raw_tx I get a hash returned, however when I look at http://blockexplorer.com the hash cannot be found.

I'm definitely on testnet.

Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Comment: http://blockexplorer.com/testnet is where you should be looking for testnet transactions.

Answer (score 2):

When using sendrawtransaction if the hash is generated but not propagated, then first I would assume that bitcoind retry mechanism will eventually send to the network.

On build 8.99 the transaction will go through, AcceptToMemoryPool. Which will validate the tx. So unless you see error TX rejected 22, which could be anything, as the validation is not yet reported. Then it's safe to assume you just need to wait.

Comment: Only if the transaction applies to your own wallet, will it be rebroadcast. Sendrawtransaction behaves exactly as if the transaction was received from the network.

Comment: @PieterWuille, Does this mean you should keep sending a transaction through sendrawtransaction until it appears on another node, or even in a block? Or would this be a bad practice and overload the network unnecessarily?

Comment: @Mark Sending invalid transactions (e.g., double-, quadruple-, etc. -spending) would increase your node's banscore; see [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/44218/4334).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as not having confirmations? BlockExplorer seems to keep it's own block database, that's only updated when a new block is reported. Your transaction won't immediately appear there.

Perhaps run `less ~/.bitcoin/debug.log` and do SHIFT + F to track for new logs. Once you submit your transaction, watch for errors which hint at the reason for failure.

If possible, try verifying it's not being broadcast by using a second node. If it's running with the txindex=1 flag, you can do `bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction <txid> 1` on arbitrary, non-wallet transactions. It should be possible after just a few seconds.