# What increases a node's banscore?

Tags: banscore

What increases a node's banscore? What factors contribute to the banscore? Does a node sending bad transactions increase its banscore? Does its using unnecessarily too much bandwidth also increase its banscore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many facts that can increase a node's banscore. A node's banscore is updated in the [Misbehaving](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L1685) function from [main.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp). Some of the reasons that trigger such update are:

- [Sending invalid blocks](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L1721).
- [Sending duplicate version messages](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L4570).
- [Not sending first a version message](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L4687) (before other communication).
- [Sending addr messages with more than 1000 addresses](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L4789).
- [Sending inv messages with more than 50000 elements](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L4864).
- [Sending header messages with more than 2000 elements](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L5115).
- [Sending too large bloom filters](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L5380).
- ...

Regarding transactions, it seems that they also may [increase](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L5042) the banscore:

> // Punish peer that gave us an invalid orphan tx

Comment: That's good that they're punished for sending invalid transactions, that way there can't be any lazy nodes out there.

Comment: does broadcasting double spend transaction also increases the banscore  ? thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't (see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/28159/3041)

Comment: Could continuously re-broadcasting a transaction that is already in all nodes' mempools increase banscore?

Comment: @deezy iiuc all nodes are continually re-broadcasting the transactions in their mempools, in order to make sure that their mempools line up with the rest of the network